# Summing Textbox Values

Tags: vba, textbox, powerpoint

I'm writing a VBA script for a specific slide in PowerPoint. When in Presentation Mode, the user will input numeric values into 5 textboxes. I would like TextBox6 to auto populate the total for TextBox1-TextBox5.

My issue is that the slide does not automatically update. If I stop presentation mode and press the run button within 'view code' it will update the slide with the total. Is there a way for this to occur while the user is running through the slide in presentation mode?

```vb
Private Sub TextBoxesSum()
    Dim Total As Double
    Total = 0
    If Len(TextBox1.Value) > 0# Then Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox1.Value)
    If Len(TextBox2.Value) > 0# Then Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox2.Value)
    If Len(TextBox3.Value) > 0# Then Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox3.Value)
    If Len(TextBox4.Value) > 0# Then Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox4.Value)
    If Len(TextBox5.Value) > 0# Then Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox5.Value)
    TextBox6.Value = Total
    TextBox6.Value =  Format(TextBox6.Value, "Standard")
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox6_Change()
    TextBoxesSum
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to remove `TextBox6_Change()` and write `TextBox1_Change()` .. `TextBox5_Change()` events for each `TextBox`, where you simply call `TextBoxesSum()` in each.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I’m a little confused which your comment. So if I understand right, the top portion of the script is alright but I need to change at the line that starts with: Private Sub TextBox6_Change.                     Do I simple write for Textbox 1 - 5?                                          Private Sub Textbox1_Change()                             TextBoxesSum                                                         End Sub

Comment: Is there was just an easier way to add TextBox1-TextBox5 and display it in TextBox6.                                                                 I wrote: Private Sub TextBox6_Sum()    TextBox6 = Val(TextBox1.Text) + Val(TextBox2.Text) + Val(TextBox3.Text) + Val(TextBox4.Text) + Val(TextBox5.Text)   End Sub         This returns the correct display but only when you select the script and press play button. Is there a way to add run macro or something within the code? TIA

Comment: Did my answer below solve your problem? If it did, please consider to click the tick mark, beside my answer, green. If it didn't please inform why not.

Answer (score 1):

Remove (that is, delete, take out)

```
Private Sub TextBox6_Change()
TextBoxesSum
End Sub
```

Then double click each of the `TextBox1` .. `TextBox5` in the design view. That will create 5 event skeletons like

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub
```

In each of those skeletons you write a call to `TextBoxesSum`

```
    TextBoxesSum
```

Is that easy enough, no?

You don't need to do any changes to the `TextBoxesSum` sub (although you could remove a couple of lines, but let's not mix up your head with that :) )

Comment: That did it, thank you!

Comment: @Justin, when someone posts an answer that solves your problem, please give them an upvote. That's what keeps this place running.

Comment: Thanks, @John , ... *or, if you don't yet have sufficient reputation to upvote, you can anyway click the tick mark beside the answer to become green, to indicate that the answer is correct.*